# How to diagnose an issue with php exec function when $return is false

Tags: php, arrays, bash

Hi I'm having a problem with a script where it is meant to run multiple times successfully. However by using the following code I have diagnosed that the script is running successfully only half the time, whereas the other half it doesn't seem to be running correctly at all.

I have figured this out using the $return value of the exec function as shown below:

```
exec("exec /bin/bash ./ygtoyn.sh $fileName $yName 2>&1", $output, $return);

if($return !== 0){ // exec is successful only if the $return_var was set to 0. !== means equal and identical, that is it is an integer and it also is zero.
   echo "File not created";
}
else{
   echo "File Created Successfully";
}

print_r($output);
```

However what I need to do is figure out why the script is not running correctly half of the time. Is there some method I can use to diagnose what the issue is? The $output variable is appearing as an empty array.

Here is the output when I run the code:

> File not created
>
> Array ( )
>
> File Created Successfully
>
> Array ( )
>
> File not created
>
> Array ( )
>
> File Created Successfully
>
> Array ( )
>
> File Created Successfully
>
> Array ( )
>
> File not created
>
> Array ( )

**UPDATE 1: I've printed out the value of $return which is 1. According to this link
[hiteksoftware](http://www.hiteksoftware.com/knowledge/articles/049.htm) that means an Incorrect Function. Can anyone explain what this might be?**

Comment: Try printing your output  `var_dump($output);`

Comment: Tried that just got this `array(0) { }`

Comment: Give this a try      print_r(error_get_last());

Comment: Nothing appears when I run it with `print_r(error_get_last());`

Comment: Did you enable php errors or just enable and try ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

Comment: Tried putting that in there but still doesn't print any errors. However I printed the value for $return which is 1. According to here [link](http://www.hiteksoftware.com/knowledge/articles/049.htm) 1 = Incorrect function.

Comment: Hi I really need help with this can anyone help me out??

Comment: As to why 1 refers to incorrect -- by convention, bash functions return 0 on success, and non-zero on failure.  This convention allows the bash functions to return different values to specify why they failed, and still allows a compare-to-zero test to see if the function was succesful.  Notice that `true; echo $?` returns 0, and `false; echo $?` returns 1.

Comment: As to why you're failing half the time, the answer will lie in the ygtoyn.sh script.  You will need to add debugging in there to output why it is returning non-zero.